# Rounding negative numbers to the nearest 1,000 that is closest to zero

Tags: python, math

I'm looking to round numbers to their nearest 1,000 closest to zero. The following code works for positive numbers

```
import math
original_number = 1245
new_number = math.floor(original_number / 1000.00) * 1000
>> 1000
```

However, when I use the code on negative numbers it moves further away.

```
import math
original_number = -1245
new_number = math.floor(original_number / 1000.00) * 1000
>> -2000
```

Comment: Yes, that's what "floor" means in a mathematical context. If you want rounding, consider looking for something named "round". (Hint: you don't need to import anything.)

Comment: What do you want for 1500 and 1501?

Comment: @kellyBundy 1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the absolute value of the number you are rounding, then preserve the sign of your number using [`math.copysign()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html),

```
import math
original_number = -1800
new_number = math.copysign(abs(original_number) // 1000 * 1000, original_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for both positive and negative number.

```py
import math
original_number = -1100
if original_number<0:
    new_number = -math.floor(abs(original_number) / 1000.00) * 1000
else:
    new_number = math.floor(original_number / 1000.00) * 1000
print(new_number)
```

OUTPUT

```py
IN:-1254, OUT:-1000
IN:-1500, OUT: -1000
IN:-1501, OUT: -1000
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
round_thousands_towards_zero = lambda num: num - (num % (num/abs(num)*1000))
```

lambdaless:

```py
def round_thousands_towards_zero(num):
    sign = num/abs(num)
    saught_multiplier = sign * 1000
    return num - (num % saught_multiplier)
```

Comment: Why are you using a lambda for this? One-liners are not always better. The official Python Style Guide says the following about this: "_Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier_". The function itself looks nice though.

Comment: I prefer writing single-operator, math-only functions as lambdas, but I added a more verbose version now

Comment: You could still `return num - (num % (num/abs(num)*1000))` inside the function. There's just no point in creating a lambda function and then assigning it to a variable (except for reducing your line count by 1).